# Intermediate files disappear in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, dem

I am working with ArcGIS 10.1 creating some slope and aspect files. I do this:

```
DEM_park = ExtractByMask(mosaic_name, park_area)
```

and it creates the DEM_park file in a default gdb with a default name. I then export this file with:

```
output = 'dem_'+'{0}'.format(parkID)+'.tif'
arcpy.CopyRaster_management(DEM_park, output, "#","#","#","#")
```

which works fine. Then I want to keep working with the DEM_park file:

```
outSlope = Slope("DEM_park", "DEGREE")
```

But it says that the file does not exist. And indeed when I go the the default gdb I cannot find the file.

I can work with the .tif file I created, but still find it irritating that my other file just disappeared. Is there a way of avoiding this?

Additional Note: this happens on a script. If I execute the lines one by one in the Python window it can find the file and calculates the slope without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is that you specify the output location.
Something like this:

```
output = "C:\\yourfolder\\yourgdb.gdb\\DEM_park"
```

Because it is not clear to me where is your DEM going, check your environment settings.

---

I see it now. You created a tif. GDB's cannot store tif format rasters, so of course it is not there at the default gdb. Then your output should be:

```
output = "C:\yourfolder\DEM_park.tif"
```